# Using Access as a frontend for SQL Server and having staging tables

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, sql-server-2014

**What we do**

We run a website that provides statistics. We used to run Access as a backend database, but now made the transition to SQL Server.

**How we work**

When we receive new statistics we put them in a staging table for proofreading and testing, before exporting them to the live database. Now we are using Access as a frontend for SQL Server with linked tables. This works fine.

What is the best way to having a Access database with staging tables that when ready can be exported to a table in SQL Server? Mind you that the final process should be fairly simple and not technical, as the reason for using Access is the relatively user-friendly UI. Using SQL Server Management Studio would be to technical for the users handling the data.

Let me stress that the solution we need is not a one-time conversion of a table or database, but for staging changes and then pushing them to SQL Server.

Comment: There are much better ways than access, have you thought of creating some winforms? Simple data entry applications are easy to make in .net and far less hassle than what you are trying to do.

Comment: We are recieving very large amount of data, that is why we don't use forms. It would take weeks to input just one set of statistics.

Comment: In that case, in that situation I would have the data input in excel and move to SQL Server using integration services. If you would like some documentation let me know.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I would like to see the documentation. I'm not sure this is the easy way we are looking for though, as they sometimes would like to be able to add fields and move data within the tables.

Comment: in what way is Excel better than Access?? the real question for the OP would be. How many users? Where are you getting the source data from?
Access can give you neat solution for multi user & very simple aggregation and upload to the live database which Excel needs extra care and additional work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using linked tables and a local staging table which we upsized when the data is ready to be updated on production database.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Move-Access-data-to-a-SQL-Server-database-by-using-the-Upsizing-Wizard-5d74c0df-c8cd-4867-8d07-e6e759d72924

Answer (score 0):

Here's some documentation on what I discussed in the comments. If you have never used integration services before the beauty of it is once the import procedure has been created it can be used over and over again.

So once you have the data in excel format, even access if you really wanted to you can follow the steps on the link below

[Creating A Simple SSIS Package](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/207/creating-a-simple-ssis-package/)